# Category-theoretic cross product and set-theoretic cross product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, cross-product

I recently proved as an exercise the associativity of cross product as defined in category theory. But in set theory, cross product is not associative. It seems intuitive to me that cross should be associative, but it also seems that the set theoretic definition doesn't cause set theorists any problems. Are there examples in which the associativity of cross does matter, so that the category theoretic def. is preferable for more than just intuitive reasons?

Comment: What do you mean by "cross product?" When you say category-theoretic cross product, I would guess you mean direct product (also sometimes known just as product). In this case, the set-theoretic product is the product in the category of sets, so it's certainly associative in the obvious sense.

Comment: The categorical product is associative only up to canonical isomorphism. But so is the set-theoretic cartesian product. This causes no problems in practice.

Answer (score 4):

The Cartesian product of sets is what is usually referred to as the product of two sets, and it is denoted with $\times$. It's certainly associative. The intuition is that when you form $(X\times Y)\times Z$ and $X\times (Y\times Z)$, they are both basically the same as the set of ordered triples $X\times Y\times Z$. While the first two are not *equal* as sets, they are "rearrangable" with a canonical isomorphism of sets so that they look alike, so there is not much reason to consider them different.

---

No longer believe the user has this problem:
<s>You might possibly be confusing it with the 3-d vector algebra [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) (denoted by the same $\times$), which is not associative. This is a product between vectors (usually from $\Bbb R^3$), not sets.</s>

Comment: What OP seems to hint at is that while there is a canonical isomorphism, there is _not_, strictly speaking, an identity.

Comment: @Lord_Farin That could be... I'll try to add a bit more to try to promote the idea we should still think of it as being associative.

Comment: Excellent now, +1.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for helping me make a better solution :)

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the answer; the intuition you mention matches my own. It was that intuition that led me to think that the def. of product in set theory is /wrong/: by not characterizing product only up to canonical isomorphism, it has lost associativity -- a property product has. So I'm after some example where the failure of associativity of set theoretic product is used in a way that seems acceptable.

Comment: Dear @user1093043, The sense in which the categorical product is associative, which you seem to accept, is "up to canonical isomorphism," not literal equality of objects, and this is the same sense in which the cartesian product of sets is associative. So why do you consider the cartesian products of sets not to be associative?