# A picky question on set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just came to this math statement:

Let A,B,C be sets. Then: (AxB)xC = Ax(BxC)

My question is, why is it so?
I mean,

(AxB)xC = { ((a1,b1),c1), ((a1,b2),c3), ... }

and

Ax(BxC) = { (a1,(b1,c1)), (a2,(b3,c2)), ... }

Is there any "hidden" assumptions on this?

Comment: Related, not duplicate: [#413177](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/413177/43351).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that they aren't equal. Rather, we have a "natural" bijection $(A\times B)\times C\to A\times(B\times C)$ given by $$\bigl\langle\langle a,b\rangle, c\bigr\rangle\mapsto\bigl\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle\bigr\rangle.$$ This map preserves a lot of the "structure" we may put on products (such as topologies), so in many senses, we may treat them as the same thing, and so many texts simply ignore the distinction.

Comment: oh...so I wasn't so picky...but why do some textbooks say "equal"?

Comment: It is likely because, for all intents and purposes that the book will consider, they are effectively the same.

Comment: @user1894397, please give some examples of textbooks where those two pretty different sets are called "equal": I think this is a rather huge mistake and perhaps there's some point in writing to the author/editors.